# Knockout advanced declaration javascript "with"-like

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm stuck in areas where I need to have a custom variable accessible everywhere in the child elements like $parents, $parent that we can reference.
Example:

```
<div data-bind:"addThisVariable: { name: '$hello', value: somethingTimeConsuming() }">
     <div data-bind="foreach: something">
         <span data-bind="text: $hello.stringReference">                 
         </span>
     </div>
</div>
```

I wonder if it's already available with Knockout, or if anyone has a tip on how to achieve this.

### I want to populate a context and its subcontexts with a variable like "$something"

But in knockout, for all contexts and child contexts of where I declared that.
So I can do potentially time consuming tasks and not have to re-run them each time.

EDIT: I don't want the "with:$something" binding which doesn't answer my answers

It would like like a temporary var that I would need to populate sub-contexts, like we would do for a

```
.forEach(function(item){
    var somethingCalculated = 1234;
    item.someArray.forEach(function(subItem) {
        var somethingElse = somethingCalculated + 567;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A while ago, I created a simple binding for myself called `let` that does what you want. Here it is:

```
ko.bindingHandlers['let'] = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // Make a modified binding context, with extra properties, and apply it to descendant elements
        var innerContext = bindingContext.extend(valueAccessor);
        ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(innerContext, element);
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings['let'] = true;
```

You would use it like this:

```
<div data-bind:"let: { $hello: somethingTimeConsuming() }">
     <div data-bind="foreach: something">
         <span data-bind="text: $hello.stringReference">                 
         </span>
     </div>
</div>
```

```js
ko.bindingHandlers['let'] = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // Make a modified binding context, with extra properties, and apply it to descendant elements
        var innerContext = bindingContext.extend(valueAccessor);
        ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(innerContext, element);
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings['let'] = true;

(function() {
    var vm = {
        foo: ko.observable("foo"),
        bar: ko.observable("bar"),
        list: ko.observableArray([
            'one', 'two', 'three'
        ])
    };
    vm.hello = ko.pureComputed(function() {
        return vm.foo() + vm.bar();
    });

    ko.applyBindings(vm);
})();
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="let: { $hello: hello() }">
    <div data-bind="foreach: list">
        <span data-bind="text: $data"></span><span data-bind="text: $hello"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Neither of these options quite gives you JavaScript's `with` (but then, JavaScript's `with` has some pretty major maintenance issues), but here are a couple of options for you:

---

Your best bet is probably a computed on (say) the container or even the root VM.

```
yourVm.hello = ko.computed({
    pure: true, // If it is, that is
    read: function() {
        // complex stuff here
    }
});
```

Example:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  var vm = {
    foo: ko.observable("foo"),
    bar: ko.observable("bar"),
    list: ko.observableArray([
      'one', 'two', 'three'
    ])
  };
  vm.hello = ko.computed({
    pure: true,
    owner: this,
    read: function() {
      return this.foo() + this.bar();
    }
  });

  ko.applyBindings(vm, document.body);
})();
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: list">
  <span data-bind="text: $data"></span><span data-bind="text: $parent.hello"></span>
</div>
```

The value of the computed will only be reevalutated if the observables it touches change value.

If you put it on the root, then `$root.hello` will always refer to it.

---

But I suppose it would be *possible* to create a custom binding that did that using syntax very like what you've shown, but I don't think I'd recommend it. Something along these lines (<s>completely untested</s> — huh, whaddyaknow, it works, see below):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.addThisVariable = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        bindingContext.$data[ko.unwrap(value.name)] = ko.unwrap(value.value);
    }
};
```

Example (but again, I really think I'd go with the computed):

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  ko.bindingHandlers.addThisVariable = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
      var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
      bindingContext.$data[ko.unwrap(value.name)] = ko.unwrap(value.value);
    }
  };

  var vm = {
    foo: ko.observable("foo"),
    bar: ko.observable("bar"),
    list: ko.observableArray([
      'one', 'two', 'three'
    ])
  };

  ko.applyBindings(vm, document.body);
})();
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="addThisVariable: { name: '$hello', value: foo() + bar() }, foreach: list">
  <span data-bind="text: $data"></span><span data-bind="text: $parent.$hello"></span>
</div>
```

That just adds it to the current VM (so further `with` or `foreach` bindings *inside* that would need `$parent` or `$parent.$parent` or whatever), but it still gives you something local you can refer to within a block of HTML.

Comment: Agreed, the main takeaway here being to work with your view model in javascript instead of hacking at it in HTML.  That said, there's custom bindings (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) and the `with` binding (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html) that you can read about.

Comment: I agree that the simplest thing would be to go for a $root call on a variable that would be used temporarily, but it does not always answer my needs, I don't want to potentially erase something and I'd like to use the ability of knockout to declare child contexts. If I'm working on a child context $root would call the wrong view model.

Comment: @Milimetric The "With" binding isn't what I need, once you go down a subcontext (foreach for example) the with binding become completely useless.

Comment: @MykaEyl: Well, then the second half of the answer does pretty much what you want, doesn't it?

Comment: I'd recommend against hacking something into the $root context, personally.  It's a "make it a global variable" approach, when really they want some form of scoping, more likely.

Answer (score 1):

Knockouts `foreach` binding has an `as` option that does what you want.  If you have an array of "somethings" and you want to be able to reference them as `$something.whatever`, then

```
<!-- ko foreach: {data: arrayOfSomethings, as: '$something'} -->
    <span data-bind="text: $something.foo"></span> <!-- works in any child context -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

If, on the other hand, you only have a single "something"... well, honestly, I'd probably recommend Michael Best's `let` binding... but if you just want something that works and doesn't require a custom binding handler...

```
<!-- ko foreach: {data: [something], as: '$something'} --> <!-- ugly but it works -->
     <span data-bind="text: $something.foo"></span> <!-- works in any child context -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

(Sidenote, I wouldn't actually recommend using "$something" as your name; I'd leave the $ prefixes for knockout-defined stuff, and just call your thing "something"; personally)